# HBase KeyValue showing encrypted value using Java Code Program

Tags: hbase, key-value

I was trying to write a simple HBase Data Manipulation In Java Code

The Code is as Follows

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Configuration hBconfig = HBaseConfiguration.create();
    hBconfig.addResource(new Path("/home/circar/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml"));
    try {
        HTable hTable = new HTable(hBconfig, "exampleHbTable");

        Result result = hTable.get(new Get(Bytes.toBytes("ExampleRow1")));

        List<KeyValue> keyValList = result.list();

        for(KeyValue keyValue : keyValList){

            System.out.println("a. Key:"+keyValue.getKeyString());
            System.out.println("a. KeyType:"+keyValue.getType());
            System.out.println("a. Row:"+keyValue.getRow().toString());
            System.out.println("a. Family:"+keyValue.getFamily().toString());
            System.out.println("a. Qualifier:"+keyValue.getQualifier().toString());
            System.out.println("a. Value:"+keyValue.getValue().toString());
            System.out.println("a. TotalColLength:"+keyValue.getTotalColumnLength());
            System.out.println("a. TimeStamp:"+keyValue.getTimestamp());

            SplitKeyValue splitKeyValue = keyValue.split();
            System.out.println("b. KeyType:"+splitKeyValue.getType());
            System.out.println("b. Row:"+splitKeyValue.getRow().toString());
            System.out.println("b. Family:"+splitKeyValue.getFamily().toString());
            System.out.println("b. Qualifier:"+splitKeyValue.getQualifier().toString());
            System.out.println("b. Value:"+splitKeyValue.getValue().toString());
            System.out.println("b. TimeStamp:"+splitKeyValue.getTimestamp());

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The Result is showing as

```
    13/06/21 18:15:29 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to         localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
    13/06/21 18:15:29 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x13f66c41fc90003, negotiated timeout = 40000
    a. Key:\x00\x0BExampleRow1\x10CircarConsultingMapReduce\x00\x00\x01?f\x16m\x0D\x04
    a. KeyType:4
    a. Row:[B@15718f2
    a. Family:[B@126f827
    a. Qualifier:[B@16dfa45
    a. Value:[B@149eb9f
    a. TotalColLength:25
    a. TimeStamp:1371807313165
    b. KeyType:[B@289d2e
    b. Row:[B@6754d6
    b. Family:[B@1f2cea2
    b. Qualifier:[B@1dc0e7a
    b. Value:[B@3a9bba
    b. TimeStamp:[B@1c5ddc9
    a. Key:\x00\x0BExampleRow1\x08ProjectsMapReduce\x00\x00\x01?f\x16m\x0D\x04
    a. KeyType:4
    a. Row:[B@163f7a1
    a. Family:[B@1690ab
    a. Qualifier:[B@173ec72
    a. Value:[B@1a85d38
    a. TotalColLength:17
    a. TimeStamp:1371807313165
    b. KeyType:[B@8046f4
    b. Row:[B@1b273cc
    b. Family:[B@d05c13
    b. Qualifier:[B@14d1d41
    b. Value:[B@1bbd7b2
    b. TimeStamp:[B@14df764
```

But it has the values as showing in the HBase Shell is as follows:

```
    ~-desktop:~$ sudo hbase/bin/hbase shell

    HBase Shell; enter 'help<RETURN>' for list of supported commands.
    Type "exit<RETURN>" to leave the HBase Shell
    Version 0.94.8, r1485407, Wed May 22 20:53:13 UTC 2013

    hbase(main):001:0> 
    hbase(main):002:0* list
    TABLE                                                                                                                        
    exampleHbTable                                                                                                               
    1 row(s) in 0.7540 seconds

    hbase(main):003:0> scan 'exampleHbTable'
    ROW                              COLUMN+CELL                                                                                 
     ExampleRow1                     column=CircarConsulting:MapReduce, timestamp=1371807313165, value=Hadoop                    
     ExampleRow1                     column=Projects:MapReduce, timestamp=1371807313165, value=MyProject                         
    1 row(s) in 0.1170 seconds

    hbase(main):004:0>
```

Would someone please provide any idea to get the actual readable value using Java Code ?

Comment: The values that you are seeing are not encrypted ones but the array of bytes stored in HBase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Bytes.toString()` provided by HBase API to convert these byte[] into their String representation. Java's toString() won't work here.

```
Example:
System.out.println("a. Row:" + Bytes.toString(keyValue.getRow()));
```

Comment: You are welcome. If it works for you perfectly you might wanna accept it as the answer so that others can benefit from it. Welcome to SO :)